# ASP.Net Core reuse default oauth2 code as much as possible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

Iam in a situation where I have to connect to a third party with oauth2 from a background service and I was wondering how this can be done without writing too much own code.

The situation:
I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 application with simple cookie authentication, some snippets for completion:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        ...
        options.LoginPath = "/Authentication/Login";
        ...
    });
```

In the login action of the AuthenticationController

```
...
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "some user identifier"));
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id))
...
```

So far, all good.

Now I want to connect to a API of a third party what's using oauth2 for some application-wide activities (for instance syncing application data). Now I can write my own oauth2 authentication logic but why would I if it's already there in the ASP.NET Core framework. So I was thinking about the following:

Extending `AddAuthentication` with `AddOAuth` and call `ChallengeResult` with the right sheme. After authentication, in the callback, save the access token in memory and the refresh token in a secure persistent storage so it can be used later by the application in some background task (`IHostedService`) in combination with a HTTP client.

So I extended `AddAuthentication`:

```
    .AddOAuth("My-Scheme", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "a client id";
        options.ClientSecret = "a client secret";
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-name-of-third-party");

        // Endpoint configs
        ...
    });
```

Next to the AuthenticationController there's a IntergrationController with a Connect action what return's the following code:

```
var redirectUrl  = ...
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
return new ChallengeResult("My-Scheme", properties);
```

After login with cookie authentication (`IntergrationController` requires authentication) and calling the `Connect` action redirects me to the third party. After entering my credentials I will be redirected back to my own application as expected. What I didn't expect was that the current user (`HttpContext.User`) was replaced with the one of the third party (instead by adding it as a `ClaimsIdentity` for instance) what breaks the application because also the name identifier is replaced by the one from the third party what doesn't match with any in my application.

What iam missing here? Why is the `HttpContext.User` replaced and how can I prevent it?

Also if you have some other thoughts about this or recommendations, please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may need two cookie/sign-in schemes: one for your own identity, and another for your third party identity. When you add OAuth scheme, set it to sign in with the third party cookie scheme, so that the third party identity is persisted in a cookie which does not replace your app's cookie:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie("cookie-your-app")
    .AddCookie("cookie-third-party")
    .AddOAuth("third-party", opt =>
    {
        opt.SignInScheme = "cookie-third-party";
    });
```

If you need to restore both identities for a method, you could use an authorization policy to combine the two cookie schemes:

```
services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("combined-cookies", builder =>
    {
        builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("cookie1", "cookie2");
        builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

So when you authorize using that policy, you should see two identities in `HttpContext.User.Identities`:

```
[Authorize("combined-cookies")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    // Two identities here
    var identities = HttpContext.User.Identities;

    return View();
}
```

For endpoints that need either one, use `Authorize` attribute accordingly to restore identity from desired cookie.

Comment: This was what I was missing indeed. Thanks!